# How to nest tuples in Python

Tags: python, nested, tuples

I am **very** new at Python. I am trying to do a tuple that contains tuples in the form `(1,(1,(1,'a')))`. I am not allowed to use any functions. I have written a list and for each element of the list I want to take tuple.

I want to take something like `(2,(3,(4,'name')))` and the result I take is `(2,3,4,'name')`.

```
b = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
for i in range(len(b)):
mytuple = (i,'name')
print(i)
mytuple = (b[2],)+mytuple
print(mytuple)
```

Comment: Maybe this will work?
b = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
for i in range(len(b)):
    mytuple = (i,'name')
    print(i)
    mytuple = (b[2],)+mytuple
print(mytuple)

Comment: Stack Overflow does not prevent you posting cost that isn't properly formatted; just pick a couple of questions on the main python feed for proof. That makes me think you have formatting issues in your actual codebase that's stopping your script from running.

Comment: To format code correctly, copy-paste it from a source file into the question box, then select everything you just pasted it (even the parts that look okay in the preview) and hit Ctrl-K. If it still gets rejected, either it's a false positive or the rejection is actually happening for a different reason.

Comment: @roganjosh: I think there's a mechanism that tries to detect some cases of misformatting, although it doesn't do a very good job.

Comment: @user2357112 news to me! "Doesn't do very well" might be the euphemism of the year :P

Comment: I think i managed to do it, I suppose I'm doing the iteration wrong? Or maybe the whole concept is wrong, I can't get the results I want.

Comment: Sorry if I'm just being slow, but are you starting with the nested tuple and trying to flatten it or are you starting with a list and trying to make a nested tuple?

Comment: i am starting with a list and trying to make a nested tuple, I'm sorry If I'm not stating this correctly, I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate reverse on b:

```
t="name"                                                                                                           
for i in range(-1,-len(b)-1,-1): 
       t=(b[i],t) 

Out: (6, (5, (4, (3, (2, (1, 'name'))))))
```

Comment: @immalee I 've corrected my code above. t=("name") changed into t="name". The initial value does not have to be a tuple, and t=("name") is not really a tuple, it is a string.

Comment: of course, sorry about that, I'm just new here, again thanks a lot :)